# Change system of coordinates, having initial and final coords, find the way

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I have points ( how many we needs) with coordinates $(x_1,y_1)$ , $(x_2,y_2)$ , $(x_3,y_3)$ ... in the cartesian System 1 ( actually, a millimetered sheet ) and the corresponding coordinates $(a_1,b_1)$ , $(a_2,b_2)$ , $(a_3,b_3)$ in another system, System 2, that we can assume cartesian.

E.g. from manual measurement I know points :
A is (334,491) in System 1, and ( 46.604856, 34.833369 ) in System 2 
B is ( 1273,209 ) in System 1, and ( 46.609281, 34.835422 ) in System 2
C is ( 1721,1032 ) in System 1, and ( 46.608634, 34.840995 ) in System 2

Surely are involved a rotation, a linear deformation and a translation. I must find them, to calculate the coordinates of an arbitrary but near point ( near to my known points ) in a system, given the coordinates in the other.

I read [Change from one cartesian co-ordinate system to another by translation and rotation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352632/change-from-one-cartesian-co-ordinate-system-to-another-by-translation-and-rotat) getting few hints, my level is far below this problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A general [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) does something like

\begin{align*}
a &= px + qy + r \\
b &= sx + ty + u
\end{align*}

so with three points and their images, you have $6$ [linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) and can solve for these 6 variables, $p,q,r,s,t,u$. One way would be [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) on a $6\times 6$ (sparse) system of linear equations. Another would be writing this as a matrix equation, similar to what I did in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2410424/35416):

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
p & q & r \\
s & t & u \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\
y_1 & y_2 & y_3 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\begin{pmatrix}
p & q & r \\
s & t & u \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\
y_1 & y_2 & y_3 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\end{align*}

So if you have the formula for [the inverse of a $3\times3$ matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_3_.C3.97_3_matrices), a bit of [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) will determine the parameters of the transformation. Bear in mind that if the three lines are collinear, you have insufficient information and will encounter a division by zero.